# variable defined inside a procedure is kept?

Tags: mit-scheme, guile

I wrote a procedure `(do-test)`.
Since the test might have some effects on the variable `env`,
I defined `env` inside `do-test` hoping that `env` would not be carried
with the procedure, so everytime I run it, I will get a fresh environment to work with.
To my surprise, my test procedures are actually carrying the previous `env`.
Please find the follwing code:

```
(define (do-test)

  (define env '(1))
  ;(define env (list 1))

  (display env)
  (if (not (equal? (car env) 1))
    (error "assertion failed.")
    'ok)

  (set-car! env 2)
  'ok)

(do-test)
(do-test)
```

I've tried to run this code using mit-scheme / guile / codepad.org, and all of which
told me runing `(do-test)` twice yielded different results.

But if I change the line `(define env '(1))` to `(define env (list 1))`, I will get the expected result.
(you can find my code [before](http://codepad.org/gRBhI7YO) and [after](http://codepad.org/DHDnzXTk) the change in codepad.org)

To my knowledge, `'(1)` and `(list 1)` should be the same except that the second will the call procedure `list`.

I'm wondering why this happens and how can I prevent the program from reusing previous values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at [R5RS](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-7.html#%_sec_4.1.2), which says that

> it is an error to alter a constant (i.e. the value of a literal
>   expression) using a mutation procedure like `set-car!` or
>   `string-set!`.

So `'(1)` and `(list 1)` are not exactly the same thing: when you are intended to build some data that would be mutated in the future, don't use quotations.

If you try to do this:

```
(define (f) (list 1))
(define (g) '(1))
(display (eq? (f) (f)))(newline)
(display (eq? (g) (g)))(newline)
```

You will get:

```
#f
#t
```

This is suggesting that `f` will make a list whenever called. But `g` will treat its list `'(1)` as a constant and that list is allocated only once, no matter how many times it is called.